# Angular $http.jsonp failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp, angular-http

I'm trying to fetch the results from [this endpoint](http://airbnbapi.org/#view-listing-info). Using GET I get  CORS error so I'm trying jsonp.

The results are

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://api.airbnb.com/v2/listings/16218947?client_id=3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty&_format=v1_legacy_for_p3&callback=angular.callbacks._0' 
because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, 
and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

My code is

```
var API_BASE_URL = 'https://api.airbnb.com/v2/';

function getListing(id) {
  var url = API_BASE_URL + 'listings/' + id + '?client_id=3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty&_format=v1_legacy_for_p3';

  var trusted = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);

  return $http.jsonp(trusted, {
    jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/javascript'
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the endpoint, even that you specified a `callback` parameter, still returns JSON which probably means that the endpoint doesn't support JSONP either.

See here: https://api.airbnb.com/v2/listings/16218947?client_id=3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty&_format=v1_legacy_for_p3&callback=angular.callbacks._0

This is JSON and not JSONP content which is what the server needs to return in this case.

Basically the way that the `$http.jsonp` is implemented is that it injects a `<script>` element in your DOM with its `src` property pointing to the url provided. But since the server doesn't wrap the JSON into a callback function (JSONP), this cannot be included as a valid script and thus the resulting error.

Since CORS and JSONP are not options, you might need to write a server side script on your domain that will act as a proxy between your domain and the remote one. Then send the AJAX request to your script.

Comment: If I'm sending the request through my domain won't I get a CORS error?

Comment: No, of course not. CORS is only a notion that exists in the sandboxed browsers and is a limitation to javascript. On your server you could execute any requests to any domain you want using a server side language such as PHP.